# Can I use capybara/rspec to match a range?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I'm testing a Rails 3.2.6 app.

Is it possible to make an Rspec/Capybara assertion that expresses, eg:

'If I ask for films between 1970 and 1990, the page should contain a film between those dates:'

For example

```
it "should show films in the the chosen date range" do
  page.should have_selector '.year',  # then something like text: range(1970..1990)
end
```

And conversely, can I check that no '.year' elements contain dates that are not in that range?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Passing a block to have_selector didn't work, but `within` did:

```
within('.year') do 
  text.to_i.should be_between(1970, 1990)
end
```

Comment: It works great. 
There is another option: [1970, 1990].should cover(1980).
But yours is better.

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
page.should have_selector('.year') do |year|
  range(1970..1990).should include(year.text.to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the `target.should be_between(x, y)` rspec syntax is more readable:

```
page.should have_selector('.year') do |year|
  i_year = year.text.to_i
  i_year.should be_between(1970, 1990)
end
```